# Plotting energy levels in stacks, on top of one another

Tags: python

I have a code that gives me different energy levels. The code and the output is shown here:

```
from numpy import*
from matplotlib.pyplot import*

N=[0,1,2,3,4]

s=0.5      
hw=1
def Energy(n):
    
    if n%2==0:
        if n==0:
            j=0.5
            E=[(n+1.5)*hw-0.1*(j-0.5)*0.5-0.0225*(j+0.5)*(j-0.5)]
            return(E)
        else:
            l=list(range(0,n+2,2))
            j1=[abs(l+s) for l in l ]
            j2=[l-s for l in l]
            j2=list(filter(lambda x:x>0,j2))
            E1=[(n+1.5)*hw-0.1*(j-0.5)*0.5-0.0225*(j+0.5)*(j-0.5) for j in j1]
            E2=[(n+1.5)*hw+0.1*(j+0.5)*0.5-0.0225*(j+0.5)*(j-0.5) for j in j2]
            return(E1+E2)
    else:
        l=list(range(1,n+2,2))
        j1=[abs(l+s) for l in l]
        j2=[abs(l-s) for l in l]
        E1=[(n+1.5)*hw-0.1*(j-0.5)*0.5-0.0225*(j+0.5)*(j-0.5) for j in j1]
        E2=[(n+1.5)*hw+0.1*(j+0.5)*0.5-0.0225*(j+0.5)*(j-0.5) for j in j2]
        return(E1+E2) 
E=[]
for n in N:
    E.extend(Energy(n))
    E.sort()
print(E)
orbital=[r'$1s_{1/2}$',r'$1p_{3/2}$',r'$1p_{1/2}$',r'$1d_{5/2}$',r'$2s_{1/2}$',r'$1d_{3/2}$',r'$1f_{7/2}$',r'$2p_{3/2}$',r'$1f_{5/2}$',r'$2p_{1/2}$',r'$1g_{9/2}$',r'$2d_{5/2}$',r'$1g_{7/2}$',r'$3s_{1/2}$',r'$2d_{3/2}$']
x = arange(len(E))

fig, ax =subplots()
ax.scatter(x, E, s=900, marker="_", linewidth=2, zorder=3)
ax.grid(axis='y')

for xi,yi,tx in zip(x,E,orbital):
    ax.annotate(tx, xy=(xi,yi), xytext=(7,-3), size=5,
                ha="center",va='top', textcoords="offset points")
ax.margins(0.1)
ylabel('energy >>')
title('Nuclear Energy levels')
```

The output is a graph containing the energy levels but spread out parallel to the x axis

[image]

What I actually need is the levels to not be spread across. I want them in a stack, one on the top of another. I tried modifying this code for that, but to no avail. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
x = arange(len(E))
```

(just before `fig, ax =subplots()`) use

```
x = [1] * len(E)
```

to have the same x-coordinate for all your levels:

[image]

You will probably want to increase the parameter `s=`, too, in your `ax.scatter()` method, for example to 90000:

```
ax.scatter(x, E, s=90000, marker="_", linewidth=2, zorder=3)
```

[image]

and change position of annotations — slightly change parameters `xy=`, `xytext=`  in your code

for xi,yi,tx in zip(x,E,orbital):
ax.annotate(tx, xy=(xi,yi), xytext=(7,-3), size=5,
ha="center",va='top', textcoords="offset points")

to (for example):

```
for xi, yi, tx in zip(x, E, orbital):
    ax.annotate(tx, xy=(.65*xi, yi), xytext=(7, 3), size=5,
                ha="center", va='top', textcoords="offset points")
```

[image]

and change the overall image size to increase gaps between levels — in your

```
fig, ax = subplots()
```

use the `figsize=` parameter:

```
fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(6.5, 12))
```

[image]

Finally, you may remove ticks from x-axis and add minor ticks to y-axis:

```
import matplotlib as mpl       # this line is better to put near the start of your code

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.MaxNLocator(50))
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to increase the gap between the lines? I tried scaling the y axis by using ylim but it only increased the axis length, not the gap.

Comment: @Ihsan, I added it to my answer.